# Adding static member variable to third-party class

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using Boost.Property_Tree for a project and I want to add a small bit of functionality to it. I want to add a "fromFile" static member variable that will figure out the file type and then use the proper parser. In my project, this is currently how I've got it.

```
typedef boost::property_tree::ptree ConfigNode;
```

Then I have another class called ConfigLoader that I've been using to load the file. I want to add the one function to a ConfigNode class though. I need the compiler to treat ConfigNode as if it were a boost::property_tree, but I want to add one static function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need a static member function?  Why not make it a non-member function?  (Or perhaps I'm missing something?)

Comment: It's mostly for organization. The typedef makes the code a lot more readable and I didn't like needing a second class for that organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  There's no *clean* way to do this.

You have two options:

1. Declare your functions and variables outside of the class completely (e.g. in another class or global in some namespace).
2. Subclass `boost::property_tree`, adding your static member(s).